# Get RecyclerView to stop scrolling when I add items to the Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I stop RecyclerView from scrolling to the bottom of the list whenever I add items?

Even when I insert something at the top of the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemInserted` the list scrolls to the bottom.

The one feature that works as expected is `notifyItemRemoved(index)`

Comment: Use stopScroll() method of Recycleview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had an item in the list, a `ProgressBar` to indicate that data was loading, but when the new items loaded I added them to the list, this moved the "focused item," the `ProgressBar` down and if there were enough items to move it off the screen then the `RecyclerView` would scroll down to keep it on screen. The problem being 1. I didn't want it to maintain "focus" and 2. The very next thing I did was remove the `ProgressBar` from the `Adapter.

So the solution is to remove the `ProgressBar` or other items before adding items earlier positions in the `Adapter`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was calling `notifyRangeInserted()` with the entire list and that was scrolling to the end of that range.

If you're having similar issues, just cut the Adapter functionality back to its bare essentials and build up from there.